# SVG transform:translate breaks input range offset

Tags: css, svg

I've discovered an issue with SVG and transform:translate An `<input type="range" />` inside a `<g>` with the style `transform:translate()` makes the drag handle invalid. You can see the bug clearly in [this CodePen](http://codepen.io/andrewray/pen/RWVGZL).

**Screenshot:** The range slider thumb is in the wrong place compared to the mouse. It's not getting the offset from the transform:translate style.

[image: Invalid]

**This problem does not happen with non-SVG markup.** You can see it working in a regular div in the CodePen.

This seems to happen in Chrome and Safari, but not Firefox.

Is this a browser bug? I've been messing around for a bit but can't find a workaround. How can I get my drag handle to be correctly positioned relative to the mouse?

Comment: Unrelated but the HTMLAttribute is `class`, not `className`, which is the DOM property.

Comment: whoops; react copypasta

Comment: I filed a bug https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=149826 but still looking for a workaround

Comment: And it seems like a bug yep. foreignObject is still unstable... If you set the position to absolute, it will even disappear... Ps : I think that svg markup is case-sensitive so it should be `<foreignObject>` but not sure when it's appended as HTML_SVGElement though

Comment: The simple workaround is to not use the css `transform:translate()` but use the `x` attribute of your `<foreignObject>` http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbKpMY

Comment: I'm using a dragging library that works by setting transform:translate. If possible I'd like the solution to still be able to work with the transform.

Comment: Then the hard workaround is to not use a `foreignObject` and draw yourself an `<input type="range"/>` mockup in pure SVG+js (not so hard actually)

Comment: This was confirmed as a bug https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=539722